# Android Studio размер шрифта

Tags: android

Как сделать так, чтобы размер шрифта установленный в настройках смартфона не касался моего приложения? Например: если в настройках поставить размер шрифта огромный, тогда в моём приложении TextView налазят друг на друга и получается очень много абзацов.

Comment: Имеет ваш вопрос смысл? Я, например, удаляю приложения, которые не умеют скалировать текст.

Comment: Вы не пользуетесь мессенджерами ?)  Мб просто не замечали

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вместо sp будет dp, то не будет учитываться scale factor. Это и есть одно из главных различий между этими значениями.

Сразу буду советовать так не делать, а при верстки учитывать возможность изменения размера шрифта пользователем. Альтернатива если в Textview будет стоять dp - вынести в настройки приложения возможность, изменить этот размер.