# Запретить специальную возможность масштабирования текста

Tags: android

На многих смартфонах есть специальная возможность изменения размера шрифта.

Ниже прилагаю изображение как собственно выглядит настройка размера.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том, что из-за этой функции некоторые тексты в моём приложении отображаются некорректно.

Как отключить распространение этой специально возможности на моё приложение?

Comment: Вы хотите что бы людям было не комфортно пользоваться Вашим приложением? Лучше оптимизируйте контролы с учётом этой возможности.

Comment: @woesss , у меня итак шрифт установлен достаточно крупный (70sp). А с этой специальной возможностью он вылазит за рамки, что делает его нечитабельным для пользователя.

Comment: что-то было подобное https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/776354/android-studio-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D1%88%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82%D0%B0/776355#776355

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Установка размера шрифта в зависимости от настроек системы считается хорошим тоном, но если очень приспичило, то можно указать размер шрифта в `dp`, а не в `sp`.

Для xml разметки:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_widht = "wrap_content"
    android:textSize = "14dp" />
```